# Which one of the following string is DCFL

Tags: automata

Is odd length pallindrome DCFL or NCFL?

### Like

1) $L=\{w1w^R\mid w \in \{0, 1\}^*\}$

### or

2) $S\rightarrow aSa\mid bSb\mid a$

### or

### Suppose odd length String like

3)$S\rightarrow aSa\mid bSb\mid aSb\mid bSa\mid a\mid b$

We get information about even length palindrome, that it can never be DCFL, but what about odd length?

Comment: Is the question supposed to be a multiple-choice question between alternatives 1, 2, and 3? Also, what is "string" referring to in the question title? I am confused.

Comment: No, all three are different string. I want to know any DCFL exists among them? I am getting trouble to find DCFL among them. Actually all of them almost same type grammar. and 3rd one not pallindrome but odd length CFL. So, are they DCFL?

Comment: Do you mean "language" instead of "string"? A *string* cannot be a DCFL because it is an *element* of a language, not a language itself.

Comment: Also, you seem to be mistaking a grammar for a language. Grammars *generate* languages, but they are not languages themselves. I recommend you go over the definitions again and try to neatly separate the concepts in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The DCFL among the three alternatives is not only a DCFL, it is a *regular* language.

(Recall that the regular languages form a subset of the DCFLs.)

Hint no. 2: The other two alternatives are essentially the same language, only over different alphabets.

Comment: @Srestha If you know what a DCFL is, I am sure you are also aware of what a regular language is. I believe my hints are generous enough; your question looks like a homework assignment, so I am afraid you will not get any more from me than that.